# How can I draw polyline on polygon in Google map?

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2

I tried to create a polyline in the polygon on google map as a route to compare with the GPS value by making it like the attached image.  Please help me.

[Attached image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z2FBRrSyotVPNDUeRqgarda9mnSpDXdE/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Your attached image isn't public. Make it public